# Video Client/Server and Document Viewer

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

I want to build a software in Flash which can do below things
Load Video from the server
Load Documents PDF/DOC from Server

Thanks in advance for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about DOC files.

But video loading is not a problem in Flash, if you wan you can check http://www.osmf.org/
And for PDF you should look here: http://code.google.com/p/purepdf/